How to specify the voice name in python/gTTS?
I have this python script on macOS:
from gtts import gTTS

text = """
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
"""

tts = gTTS(text, lang='en')
tts.save("MyFile.mp3")

this works perfectly but it uses a voice that I don't want.
I want this voice called en-US-Journey-D that I see on the google gtts page.
Is there a way to specify the voice name on the python script?
I am not finding any documentation about it.
